# 'float' object is not iterable applying lambda funtion

Tags: python, pandas

I've this issue when applying this lambda function:

```
stack['norm_val'] = stack.value.apply(lambda x : (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)), axis=1)
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Below the dataset

```
   stack = pd.DataFrame([['AAA', 22.232513666152954],
       ['BBB', 3.2749810218811035],
       ['CCC', 116.79930114746094],
       ['DDD', 23.851191759109497],
       ['EEE', 75.8379271030426]], columns = (['name','value']))
```

The expected result should be a new column in the dataframe 'norm_val' with normalized values

```
   [0.16699094],
   [0.        ],
   [1.        ],
   [0.18124936],
   [0.63918415]
```

The issue is, the values are floats, I guess, how iterate over these values and apply with lambda function?

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution working with scalars, so not possible use `min`, `max` functions.

In pandas you can working with column like `Series`, so use [`Series.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) and [`Series.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) for normalize column:

```
stack['norm_val'] = (stack['value']-stack['value'].min())/
                    (stack['value'].max()-stack['value'].min())
print (stack)
  name       value  norm_val
0  AAA   22.232514  0.166991
1  BBB    3.274981  0.000000
2  CCC  116.799301  1.000000
3  DDD   23.851192  0.181249
4  EEE   75.837927  0.639184
```

Or:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = stack[['value']].to_numpy()
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
stack['norm_val'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

Comment: I think I need a break ;)